# Writing a C function to take in an english sentence as parameter and return the longest length word in the sentence

Tags: arrays, c, string, function

I have an assignment that requires me to write a function to take in an array containing an English sentence and return the length of the longest word in that sentence. This is the code I have so far:

```
int longWordLength(char *s); // Function prototype

int main() {
    char str[80], *p;

    printf("Enter a string: \n");
    fgets(str, 80, stdin);

    if (p = strchr(str,'\n'))
        *p = '\0'; //converts newline to null

    printf("longWordLength(): %d\n", longWordLength(str));
    return 0;
}

int longWordLength(char *s) {
    int count = 0, max = 0;
    while (*s++ != '\0') {
        if ((*s >= 'a' && *s <= 'z') || (*s >= 'A'&& *s <= 'Z')) {
            count++;
        } else {
            if (count > max) {
                max = count;
                count = 0;
            } else
                count = 0; // word is not the longest
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

I have tried for a long time to diagnose the issue but to no avail.

This works with certain test case like:

Test Case 1:

```
Enter a string:  
I am happy.
longWordLength(): 5
```

but for a test case like
Test Case 4:

```
Enter a string:  
Hello
longWordLength(): 4 <- it prints 4 instead of 5.
```

I am not allowed to use any library other than the `<string.h>` as it is for my school assignment. Seeking anyone's kind guidance on my issue as I really can't seem to figure out the issue. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: You don't need to count characters. Just look for blanks. Remove leading blanks. Each time you encounter a blank a word has ended. When you reached a blank, advance to the next non-blank as there could be consecutive blanks between words.

Comment: `while (*s != '\0') { /* ... your code ... */ s++; }`

Comment: *"any library other than the <string.h>"* - I'd phone the prof and ask if they really intend you to be authoring your own `printf` and `fgets` then, because *neither* are in `<string.h>`

Comment: Compile your C code using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`, improve your C code to get no warnings, then use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger to understand the behavior of your program. Improve your C code (hoping to improve that behavior), and repeat all till satisfied

Comment: Okay, thank you for that suggestion. I have been trying to debug my program by adding a comment section at the bottom of the page and running it as though I am a compiler. However, I could be wrong as my fundamental is not strong. I have been trying to troubleshoot this issue for almost 2hours to no avail, thus turning to the stackoverflow community. I have since resolve my issue. Thanks everyone for the kind inputs! It is very encouraging for me, a beginner in programming as my major is in mechanical engineering. You guys are amazing

Comment: For fun: `&`, meaning "and" comes from Latin "et".  "&c" means "etc".  One could consider & a  [27th letter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampersand#Etymology).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Interesting read! `&` was indeed considered the [27th letter in the English alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampersand#Etymology) in the late 19th century, but it was already in use in Roman times (possibly invented by [Tiro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcus_Tullius_Tiro), Cicero's secretary, when the [classical Latin alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_alphabet#Classical_Latin_alphabet) only had 23 letters (no J, U, W).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in `while (*s++ != '\0') {`: you increment the string pointer before testing the character it points to. Just change to code to:

```
    for (; *s != '\0'; s++) {
        ...
```

Note however that the last word will not be tested the maximum length if it is not followed by some separator such as a space or a newline, which you would have stripped.

Note that stripping the trailing newline is not required for `longWordLength()` to determine the correct count.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int longWordLength(const char *s); // Function prototype

int main() {
    char str[80];

    printf("Enter a string: \n");
    if (!fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin))
        return 1;

    // no need to strip the newline for this test:
    printf("longWordLength(): %d\n", longWordLength(str));
    return 0;
}

int longWordLength(const char *s) {
    int count = 0, max = 0;
    for (;; s++) {
        if ((*s >= 'a' && *s <= 'z') || (*s >= 'A'&& *s <= 'Z')) {
            count++;
        } else {
            if (count > max) {
                max = count;
            }
            if (*s == '\0')
                break;
            count = 0;  // reset the counter for the next word
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: Hello chqrlie, thank you for clarifying my initial blunder of incrementing the string pointer before my counter even begin counting. Unfortunately, I am not able to modify the code in the int main() function (due to it being a homework assignment). Thus in the main code, it actually converts the newline to a null character. Is there a way to check for the last word count suppose there is no non-alphabetic character in the last word. For example just a single "hello" input.

Comment: I know its not the most efficient but what I did was I introduced another pointer variable and replaced the '\0' with a '\n' in the function since I was not able to modify the main function. Now my code works already. It is not the cleanest nor I feel, a correct solution but it works.
 Key takeaway from this question: 
1) Don't increment the pointer variable before counting 
2) The null character is "attached" to the last word. therefore if i check for null character condition, the last word will not be counted. thus, i need to modify the '/0' to be a special character.

Comment: @Lucas: don't patch the string, remove the test for `'\0'` in the loop and test for the null terminator **after** checking for the max length as posted in my version.

Comment: @Lucas: it is pity the `main()` function uses `fgets(str, 80, stdin);` without testing for success and `if (p = strchr(str,'\n'))`: an unparenthesized assignment used as a test (a **very sloppy** style IMHO). It should be `if ((p = strchr(str,'\n')) != NULL)`

Comment: Okay! Thank you for the other tip of running the infinite for loop and breaking out only when null character is detected at the lower portion. It helped a lot in some of my other assignments! Regards!